# what is the difference between pyobjc and pyodbc?

Tags: python

```
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
 command: 'c:\users\yogesh\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\python.exe' -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\yogesh\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-i1udmkgw\\pyobjc-framework-SyncServices\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\yogesh\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-i1udmkgw\\pyobjc-framework-SyncServices\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base 'C:\Users\yogesh\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-pip-egg-info-8e_8sxie'
     cwd: C:\Users\yogesh\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-i1udmkgw\pyobjc-framework-SyncServices\
Complete output (9 lines):
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\yogesh\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-i1udmkgw\pyobjc-framework-SyncServices\setup.py", line 26, in <module>
    Extension(
  File "C:\Users\yogesh\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-i1udmkgw\pyobjc-framework-SyncServices\pyobjc_setup.py", line 390, in Extension
    os_level = get_os_level()
  File "C:\Users\yogesh\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-i1udmkgw\pyobjc-framework-SyncServices\pyobjc_setup.py", line 200, in get_os_level
    with open("/System/Library/CoreServices/SystemVersion.plist", "rb") as fp:
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/System/Library/CoreServices/SystemVersion.plist'
----------------------------------------
```

ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output

Comment: If you posted the code  or command that resulted in that error we might be able to help you debug it.

Comment: Please be a bit more specific when asking a question: *What have you tried so far with a code example?* / *What do you expect?* / *What error do you get?* **For Help take a look at "[How to ask](//stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)"**

Answer (score 1):

[PyObjC](https://pyobjc.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) is a bridge between Python and Objective-C.

[pyodbc](https://pypi.org/project/pyodbc/) is an open source Python module that makes accessing ODBC databases simple.